# Parsing erroneous XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, inputstream

I have a problem. I am calling a link which is returning XML. I have to parse this xml but the xml is not properly formatted. The xml is shown below:

```
<string>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
    <tag1>TAG1</tag1>
    <tag2>TAG2</tag2>
    <tag3>TAG3</tag3>
    <tag4>TAG4</tag4>
</string>
```

I have no option but to parse this errorneous xml any how. 
 I am getting InputStream, is this InputStream can be changed on the fly?
Any solution to the above mentioned problem would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by inputStream can be changed on the fly ?

Comment: I am getting InputStream from that link which contains errorneous xml response how can I change that xml. Supponse if I remove <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> then I would be able to parse the xml.

Comment: got it, what is response from WebService ? It sends XML but in which format, as String ?

Comment: Get them to fix the other end. It is quite ridiculous to try to compensate for garbage input at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

As you know java streams framework uses wrapper (decorator) pattern. Streams can wrap other streams and add some specific functionality. You can follow this pattern too. Take a look on `BufferedInputStream`. You can implement something similar and probably even inherit `BufferedInputStream`. Your stream will remove pattern `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>` that is on invalid place in your "`XML`". So, produced stream will be correct XML that can be parsed by regular XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the `xml` before parsing it just look for a line beginning with:

```
<?xml ...
```

And remove this line.
After this point you can use your normal `xml` parsers with your new `xml`.

you can use *apache*'s `IOUtils` library with *Java*'s `String#replaceAll` with the help of some `regex` (if you need) to remove the unwanted line from your `xml` file before inputting it to the parsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse text in some language, your first step is to define the language that you intend to parse. So far you have only given us one example of a text in that that language. We have no way of knowing what other "erroneous XML" you might want to parse: for example would you want to parse

```
<?xlm vresion="1,0 decoding="utf-9">a<b>c
```

perhaps?

Once you have defined the language that you want your program to accept, you can start writing a parser for it. If the language is reasonably close to XML, then a reasonable strategy might be for your parser to convert the text to XML and then parse the XML.

If the only difference between your language and XML is that you want to allow an XML declaration to appear anywhere, and if you're not too concerned with "edge cases" such as preserving the content of arbitrary comments and CDATA sections, then a reasonable strategy would be to preprocess the file replacing all occurrences of `<?xml` by `<?xxml`.